# Is there a way to publish keyboard events (using key_teleop for example) to a serial port?

Tags: ros, rosserial, ros-kinetic, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been looking at ways to publish keyboard commands to a UART serial port and the top result keeps pointing me to rosserial, but I'm not entirely sure this exactly fits my needs. Ideally, I want to be able to send keyboard events to my flight controller through PPM signals because I already have the hardware that would send signals from a serial port to my flight controller. This is how I envision it would go from all the materials I have:

KEYPRESS (Twist message) ==> UART SERIAL PORT (probably ttyS1) ==> PPM ENCODER (not an Arduino) ==> FLIGHT CONTROLLER

I found that I can publish Twist messages using either the key_teleop module or teleop_twist_keyboard, but I'm stuck as to how to send this to a serial port (i.e. ttyS1). Would I simply need to write my own ROS node and use pyserial (since I would be writing in python) to open the port and pass the message in? Or can I use rosserial somehow to pass in Twist messages?

Thank you in advance and please excuse me for asking a noob question.

Trixie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285330/is-there-a-way-to-publish-keyboard-events-(using-key_teleop-for-example)-to-a-serial-port?/) by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosserial` will assume control over your serial port, so if that port is being used by something else -- and that 'something' is not a `rosserial` client -- that is probably not what you want.

> Would I simply need to write my own ROS node and use pyserial (since I would be writing in python) to open the port and pass the message in?

If you're basically trying to *convert* ROS `geometry_msgs/Twist` msgs into something your remote system can use, then yes, you'll probably have to write a node that does this for you.

Please take the time to first search for an existing solution / implementation though, as it's likely someone (or multiple someones) has (have) already done this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1